# Convergence of stochastic processes via convergence of infinitesimal generators

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Given a sequence of sequence processes $(X_N(\cdot))_{N \geq 0}$, I want to show this sequence converges to another process $X(\cdot)$ by considering that the sequence of generators $(A_N)_{N \geq 0}$ converge to some generator $A$ which corresponds to the process $X$. Could someone please point towards a proposition for a textbook (or if not a research paper) for me to refer to when doing this? Also, I think there are some further details here linked to the cores of the generators which I am unclear on, so it would be helpful to see a proposition/ theorem which clearly outlines the required conditions. Thanks.

Comment: The book by Ethier & Kurtz contains results of this type (Ethier, S.N., Kurtz, T.G.: *Markov Processes - Characterization and Convergence*).

Comment: What chapter or page?

Comment: Page 225-234 I guess. I am also interested in this topic.

Comment: @saz you know of a reference that contains functional equations? i.e non markovian

Comment: My answer to this question was deleted (for reasons which must be bizarre) so let me say here that such a statement can be found in Kallenberg's book "Foundations of Modern Probability" (2nd Edition) Theorem 19.25 on page 385.